# Change imported model orientation

Tags: modeling, camera, import

This is what I get when I import a character in Blender :

[image]

As you can see the character is not in the right position. I would like to see it "standing".

Can I rotate the camera like this ? (here I just rotated the screenshot I took)

[image]

Or is my only solution to rotate the character itself ?

Comment: What type of model are you importing?

Comment: Either .3ds or .obj files.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fix this, no need to move the camera to compensate for the orientation of the mesh. You can rotate the mesh by adjusting the rotation in the properties tab, you can also use the mesh tab. You can also do this for many method for multiple objects. Just select the object that need to be fixed and rotate them via <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>90</kbd>

[image]

You can also fix this when you import the mesh. I am assuming you are importing as .obj but this should also work for others. When you import the mesh set the *Foawrd* axis to -Y and the *Up* axis to Z.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer Vader. I used .3ds file in my question. The character comes with many different meshes (hair, ears, legs...) which makes it not very convenient if I have to rotate them one by one. Is there a faster way ?

Comment: @Lior can you select them all using `a` then rotating?

Comment: @Lior Try `A` > Select all > `R` > (axis to rate on, `X`, `Y`, or `Z`) > `90`,

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it right directly when I imported the model as suggested by Vader. By the way, "A" doesn't appear to select anything on my PC (Blender 2.69, QWERTZ keyboard), it just toggles a little option on the bottom of my screen, which I have no idea what it does, I will see this later. Thanks again

Comment: Your mouse needs to be over the 3d view. Blender keyboard shortcuts are context sensitive, meaning that depending on where the mouse is hovering over in the application it does different things.